# How to show the time in user readable format in smarty template?

Tags: php, date, datetime, smarty, unix-timestamp

I'm using PHP and Smarty for my website.

I'm storing date and time into database using Unix timestamp value. Now when I display this date in a Smarty template it should be in user readable format. So how should I convert this date into following user redable format?

For example the Unix Timestamp value is:`1395009600`. Then , it should display this date as `Mar 16 2014, 10:40 pm`.

Also I need a date in following format as well `16/03/2014(i.e. DD/MM/YYYY format)` to be displayed into smarty template.

Comment: `date('d/m/Y', $row['timeFromDB']);`

Comment: The answer to this question could have been easily found by simply googling it.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Smarty Date_format](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format)

assume $timestamp is the var having unix timestamp...
in smarty it should be like {$timestamp|date_format:"%d-%m-%Y"}

p.s. arguments are not same as in PHP date() function so MUST check link.